# how to auto populate Django Rest Framework Model fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Trying to auto populate model attributes using Django rest framework

**Intro:** I have 2 models `Patient` and `Embryo` There is only 1 user who is the superuser. All patients belong to the superuser. One patient can have many embryos but an embryo can have only one patient.

**What I want to achieve** The Embryo model has a field called `karyotes` which is a `Charfield`. when the user inputs the `karyotes` the `sex` of the embryo is auto-populated. The same with down-syndrome (see models below)

**The Error:** The way I have made my models The `sex` and `down_syndrome` always show null

[image]

```
Example (This is not code, just explanation )
    if karyotype == "46,XX" #The embryo is a Female
    if karyotype == "46,XY" #The embryo is a Male 
    if karyotype == "47,XY,+21" #The embryo is a Male and has Down Syndrome           
    if karyotype == "47,XX,+21" #The embryo is a Female and has Down Syndrome            
    else sex == null and down_syndrome == null
```

**Below are my models**

```
class PatientsApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """ Handles Creating, reading and updating Patients """

class Embryo(models.Model):
    """ A ForeignKey model to the patient """
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name="embryos", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    karyotype = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    down_syndrome = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ("M", "Male"),
        ("F", "Female"),    
    )
    sex = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code_name


""" Below is my attempt to get the desired result """
    def get_sex(self):
        if self.karyotype == "46,XX":
            return self.sex == "F"
        elif self.karyotype == "46,XY":
            return self.sex == "M"

    def has_down_syndrome(self):
        if self.karyotype == "47,XY,+21":
            return self.down_syndrome == True and self.sex == "M"
        elif self.karyotype == "47,XX,+21":
            return self.down_syndrome == True and self.sex == "F"
        else:
            return self.down_syndrome == False and self.sex == null
```

**Below are my views.py**

```
class EmbroApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles Creating, reading and updating Patients"""

    serializer_class = serializers.EmbryoSerializer
    queryset = Embryo.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    search_fields = ("code_name", "karyotype", "sex", "down_syndrome",)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
```

**below are my serializers.py**

```
class EmbryoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Embryo
        fields = ("id", "patient", "code_name", "karyotype", "sex", "down_syndrome", "created_at", "updated_at")
        extra_kwargs = {"sex": {"read_only": True},
                        "down_syndrome": {"read_only": True}
                        }
```

As per @Ruddra 1st advise

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to override the model's save method like this:

```
class Embryo(models.Model):

    ...

    def set_sex(self):
        if self.karyotype == "46,XX":
            self.sex = "F"
        elif self.karyotype == "46,XY":
            self.sex = "M"

    def set_down_syndrome(self):
      if self.karyotype == "47,XY,+21":
          self.down_syndrome = True
          self.sex = "M"
       elif self.karyotype == "47,XX,+21":
          self.down_syndrome = True
          self.sex = "F"
      else:
          self.down_syndrome = False

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.sex:
             self.set_sex()
        self.set_down_syndrome()
        return super(Embryo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also you need to change following methods in model:

```
def get_sex(self):
    if self.karyotype == "46,XX":
        return "F"
    elif self.karyotype == "46,XY":
        return "M"

def has_down_syndrome(self):
    if self.karyotype == "47,XY,+21":
        return True, "M"
    elif self.karyotype == "47,XX,+21":
        return True, "F"
    else:
        return False, None
```

**FYI** Its seems you don't need to store `sex` and `down_syndrome` information in DB as you have `karyotype` already which contains relevant information. You can try like this:

```
#models.py
GENDER_CHOICES = { "M" : "MALE", "F" : "FEMALE"}

class Embryo(models.Model):
    # remove sex and down_syndrome fields from Model
    ...
    @property
    def sex(self):
        if "46,XX" in self.karyotype:
            return GENDER_CHOICES.get("F")
        elif '47,XY' in  self.karyotype:
           return GENDER_CHOICES.get("M")
        return ""

    @property
    def down_syndrome(self):
      if '+21' in self.karyotype:
          return True
      return False


#serializer
class EmbryoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sex = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    down_syndrome = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = Embryo
        fields = ("id", "patient", "code_name", "karyotype", "sex", "down_syndrome", "created_at", "updated_at")
```

Comment: I don't know why ` return self.sex = "F"` gives a syntax error. I have added a image in the question above. Also if I remove `sex` and `down_syndrome` fields from Model How will `return "M"` and `return "F"` make sense

Comment: sorry, my bad. Please see my updated anwer. @SamirTendulkar

Comment: Awesome that worked. I don't have a `get` method in my` views `I am using `model ViewSets`.   It is working without it. Can I leave it as is

Comment: Well, i meant the get methods inside model. Sorry, i didn't clear it.

Comment: You don't need to change anything in viewset :)

Comment: I din't even need that part of the code. It just worked without it. Just the 1st code block did the trick for me. Thank again that solved a big problem of mine